# Print a character 1-15 times

Tags: python

I need to find a way to print a number/letter 1 - 15 total times, I'll have to rinse/repeat for the entire alphabet.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaa
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
```

Comment: It'd be lovely to know what you're tried to solve your homework first.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight up way is to create the string containing 1 - 15 of the same character, and then print it. For this, use the fact that `str`s can be multiplied by `int`s like so:

```
print('a'*15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another hint you're probably looking for:

You can use ASCII/Unicode numbers to generate the alphabet like so:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('z')
122
>>> chr(97)
a
>>> chr(122)
z
```

so:

```
>>> print(','.join([chr(_) for _ in range(97,123)]))
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
```

Note that we make the end of the range `123` because for [`range(start, stop [,step])`: `For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#range)

[`For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#range)

So what you can do, putting it together with [jmd_dk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46964136/2718295) is something like:

```
for i in range(97,123):
    for j in range(15, 0, -1):
        print(chr(i)*j)
```

Good luck with your homework!

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def letters():
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    yield from alphabet

for letter in letters():
    num = 1
    while num <= 15:
        print(letter * num)
        num += 1
```

Comment: What is the point of the `letters` generator? Why not just `for letter in string.ascii_lowercase`? The while loop is also one of the most basic forms of for loop - `for num in range(1, 16)`.

Comment: I knew that would be the first comment ;)

I did this for two reasons: 

1) To demonstrate explicitly that the type of pattern you want for this is some sort of iterator spitting out your alphabet (or whatever you're working with). Same reason for the while loop with explicit counter increment, I'm trying to demonstrate more explicit overall patterns / logic here.

2) To make it so that, if this is a homework assignment, the student at least has to do a bit more work, or the teacher will know this was outside-assisted

3) Because I felt like it. Feel free to edit

Comment: the point is why mix idiomatic python (generator) with non-idiomatic python (explicit incrementer instead of `range()`)?